# Determine if iOS device can support HEVC encoding

Tags: swift, encode, codec, hevc, h.265

My problem is I want to use `AVVideoCodecHEVC`. I know that it's only available in iOS 11, but device's without the A10 chip do not support it.

So, using 
`if #available(iOS 11.0, *) { let self.codec = AVVideoCodecHEVC }`
Will throw `Cannot Encode` error if using a device like an iPhone 6 that doesn't have the A10 chip. Has anyone been able to figure out if a device running iOS 11, can support HEVC?

Comment: What about [`availableVideoCodecTypes `](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/avcapturevideodataoutput/1389227-availablevideocodectypes) ?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can check if an iOS device or Mac has hardware encoding support using VideoToolbox:

```
/// Whether or not the current device has an HEVC hardware encoder.
public static let hasHEVCHardwareEncoder: Bool = {
    let spec: [CFString: Any]
    #if os(macOS)
        spec = [ kVTVideoEncoderSpecification_RequireHardwareAcceleratedVideoEncoder: true ]
    #else
        spec = [:]
    #endif
    var outID: CFString?
    var properties: CFDictionary?
    let result = VTCopySupportedPropertyDictionaryForEncoder(width: 1920, height: 1080, codecType: kCMVideoCodecType_HEVC, encoderSpecification: spec as CFDictionary, encoderIDOut: &outID, supportedPropertiesOut: &properties)
    if result == kVTCouldNotFindVideoEncoderErr {
        return false // no hardware HEVC encoder
    }
    return result == noErr
}()
```

A much higher level way to check is to see if `AVAssetExportSession` supports one of the HEVC presets:

```
AVAssetExportSession.allExportPresets().contains(AVAssetExportPresetHEVCHighestQuality)
```

See [“Working with HEIF and HEVC” from WWDC 2017](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2017/511/) for more info.

Comment: `AVAssetExportSession.allExportPresets()` worked perfectly! than you!

Comment: I appreciate the depth of this answer, and the way it was written.

Answer (score 3):

[HEVC media on Apple devices](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT207022)

When using iOS 11 or later, these devices can capture media in HEIF or HEVC format:

```
iPhone 7 or iPhone 7 Plus or later
iPad (6th generation)
iPad Pro (10.5 inch)
iPad Pro 12.9-inch (2nd generation)
```

Answer (score 1):

Use AVFoundation:

```
let isHEVC = AVOutputSettingsAssistant.availableOutputSettingsPresets().contains(.hevc3840x2160)
```

...or other presets from the **AVOutputSettingsPreset** enum